# Convert Excel to Word using Aspose.Word for Java

Tags: java, aspose

I have a requirement to convert excel template to word. Then using Aspose.Word for JAVA I can merge all word templates (including the converted excel template) to PDF file.

Aspose, iText, POI, Jasper, Birt etc doesn't support this. Is there any API in Java which allows this kind of conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, you cannot convert Excel spreadsheets to Word documents directly via `Aspose.Cells` APIs. FYI, `Aspose.Cells` is a spreadsheet management library that manages MS Excel file formats only. We have another component i.e., `Aspose.Words` that manages or merges MS word documents. But, I think for your specific requirements, you have to use two Aspose APIs with two steps, that are; `Aspose.Cells` & `Aspose.Pdf` to achieve your goal. You will use [Aspose.Cells APIs](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Converting+Excel+to+PDF+Files) that allows you to convert the spreadsheet formats (XLS/XLSX, etc.) to PDF format. Then you will use [Aspose.Pdf APIs](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfjava/Convert+PDF+to+DOC+or+DOCX+format) which allows you to convert PDF to Word document for your needs.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks Amjad, I have received your reply on Aspose forum also. Appreciate your work and solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents..
have a look here 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

Comment: Santhati, if you see my description I have clearly mentioned that I have to convert not just data but with format. And Apache POI I have already explored, it just allows to fetch content and write in whatever format you want. My requirement is to transfer not just data, but formatting also.